# c# how do i cut a string with a random length in half?

Tags: c#, string

i am trying to learn programming by doing some simple exercises online.
and after searching i couldn't find a answer.

Problem:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get sentence
        Console.WriteLine("type a sentence: ");
        string Sentence = Console.ReadLine();

        // insert code for cutting sentence in half

        // display first half of the sentence
        Console.Write(firstHalf);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: What solutions did you try or think about?

Comment: In half lengthwise or widthwise?

Comment: `string firstHalf = Sentence.Substring(0, Sentence.Length / 2);`

Comment: If it is 3 characters long how large do you expect the first half to be? What about 5 characters long? 7 characters long?

Comment: Are you asking based on words or alphabets only?

Comment: `and after searching i couldn't find a answer.` I don't think you searched hard enough. This exact question might not yet be here but if you searched `how to get string length` and `how to split string by amount of characters` you would have the answer...

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, how did you search? may be we can help you with the searching pattern, so that you can find the next solution much easier ?=!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that.

```
string firsthalf = Sentence.Substring(0, Sentence.Length/2);
```

The first parameter `0` is the starting point of the substring and the second denotes how many characters the substring should include.

The [String.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property helps you to determine the length of the string.

**Important note:**

When you divide the length by 2 you need to know that it is an integer division! That means that `3/2 = 1` and `1/2 = 0` so if your string is only 1 character long you will be an empty string as the first half ;) and if it is 3 letters long you get only the first letter.

Good fortune with the learning :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of the string using the `Length` property and use `Substring` to take half of the string

```
 firstHalf = s.Substring(0, s.Length / 2)
```

Comment: This doesn't handle odd length strings, but does handle even very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the range operator `..`:

```
var firstHalf = sentence[..(sentence.Length / 2)];
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=net-7.0):

```
var firstHalf = sentence.Remove(sentence.Length/2);
```